# Why does JS WebSocket get stuck on CONNECTING in sparkjava?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, spark-java

Here is my websocket code:

```java
@WebSocket
public class SocketServer {
    BetterLogger logger = new BetterLogger(Main.logger) {{
        loggerName = "socket-server";
    }};
    public static class ConnectionInit {
        String tty;
        String device;
    }

    static class ConnectionOpenResponse {
        String tty;
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session user) throws Exception {
        Main.logger.info("Websocket connected!");
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(Session user, int statusCode, String reason) {
        Main.logger.info("Websocket disconnected!");
        Main.sessions.closeSession(user);
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(Session user, String message) {
        Main.logger.info("Recevied websock connection: " + message);
        
        try {
            if (Main.sessions.contains(user)) {
                // treat as raw buffer
                Main.sessions.write(user, message);
            }
            else {
                ConnectionInit heartbeat = Main.gson.fromJson(message, ConnectionInit.class);
                String s = Main.config.getTTY(heartbeat.device + '.' + heartbeat.tty);

                // make sure that the tty exists in config
                if (s == null)
                    user.close(400, "Invalid device/tty!");

                // get UUID
                Main.sessions.newSession(s, user);

                logger.info("created session (" + user + ") with dev " + heartbeat.device + ":" + heartbeat.tty);
                user.getRemote().sendString(Main.gson.toJson(new ConnectionOpenResponse() {{
                    tty = s;
                }}, ConnectionOpenResponse.class));
            }
        }
        catch (SessionException e ) {
            user.close(500, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            user.close(400, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // wtf
        }
    }

}
```

I have registered it correctly in my `Main` class, and all seems to work well when I attempt to connect to it using `websocat`, I can send data and all works well. However, as soon as I create a webpage, the websocket never even opens:

```js
console.log("ws://" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + "/device");
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + "/device");
var term = new Terminal();

term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
term.write('Press enter to re-flush buffers\n');

//while(socket.readyState !== 1);
//console.log("connected!");

socket.send("testdata");

term.onData( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.charCodeAt(0) == 13)
        socket.send('\n');
    socket.send(data);
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    term.write(event.data);
});
```

Now, the code prints out the correct URL (`ws://localhost:16838/device`), however, it is stuck at `CONNECTING`, and throws the following error (which I expect because it's still connecting):

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
```

Looking at my server logs, I can see that it does print `Websocket connected!`, which doesn't even make any sense. Any help with fixing why my JS websocket client gets stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add the open event or else it doesnt actually open